# Wordpress use in one module of laravel application

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, store

I want to know if it's possible to use WordPress in one module of Laravel application.

For example, this is my website furniture.com, which uses Laravel 
Now I want to use furniture/store.com with WordPress although my main web application is in Laravel. I want to how can this be done.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not have everything in Laravel? What do you want wordpress to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to use only the same database?
It is possible to install WordPress under a new folder (in your example: /store). 
Try this solution: [intalling WP  in a subdirectory](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-step-by-step/)